# ImageMagick extend canvas when pasting

Tags: imagemagick

I have 3 images 300x400 pixels each.
I want to paste them horizontally but I want the canvas of each image to be 350x400.

Not all images are 300 width, some are 310 px, some 320 px.

I know how to extend the canvas of an image individually but I would like to know if I can do my task directly without having to expand each image one by one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read all three images into a single IM command, make all the canvasses the same dimensions, and append them into a horizontal row with a simple command like this...

```
magick img1.png img2.png img3.png -gravity center -extent 350x400 +append result.png
```

To set a background color, or "none", that shows in any overflow areas put "-background red" ahead of the "-extent" operation in the command.